# IOS: manage element in some UIViews

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, tags, label

In my app I have 5 UIView in my viewcontroller and each view has inside 6 UILabel. 
For each label I set a tag in each view, for example:

In first UIView: firtLabel tag 101, secondLabel tag 102 exc...
In second UIView: firtLabel tag 101, secondLabel tag 102 exc...
In third UIView: firtLabel tag 101, secondLabel tag 102 exc...
exc...

and for each UIView I set a tag, for example:
for first UIView tag 1
for second UIView tag 2
exc...

then in my code I do:

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){

    UIView *viewSingle = (UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:i+1];
    UILabel *data1 = (UILabel*)[viewSingle viewWithTag:100+i+1];
    [[data1 setText:[array1 objectAtIndex:i]];
    UILabel *data2 = (UILabel*)[viewSingle viewWithTag:100+i+2];
    [[data2 setText:[array2 objectAtIndex:i]];

    exc...
}
```

this code change only labels in first UIView and not in other UIView, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use **i** when you calculate the tag for retrieving UILabels. For example

```
UILabel *data1 = (UILabel*)[viewSingle viewWithTag: 101];
```

instead of

```
UILabel *data1 = (UILabel*)[viewSingle viewWithTag: 100 + i + 1];
```

Comment: OH my GOD, I'm stupid... I thought that there was a problem with tags, instead there was a stupid problem...thanks